# How do I get monetization insights for my page with Facebook API using java?

Tags: java, facebook-insights, restfb

For some reason i get the error:

"Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#200) Monetization metrics are only visible for Page admins with access to monetization insights. (code 200, subcode null) 'null - null'"

Although when I access the same video insight through Facebook's Graph API, it gives me the value no problem.

```
private void totalCpm() {
    if (tickBox2.isSelected()) {
        FacebookClient fbClient2 = new DefaultFacebookClient(pageToken, com.restfb.Version.VERSION_3_2); 
        int i=0;
        for (i=0; i<=x-1; i++){    
            Connection<Insight> insightCon2 = fbClient2.fetchConnection(vidList[i] + "/video_insights", Insight.class, Parameter.with("metric", "total_video_ad_break_ad_cpm"));

            for (List<Insight> insights: insightCon2) {
                for (Insight insight : insights) {
                    insightList4 = (insight.getValues().toString());
                    insightList5 = insightList4.replaceAll("\\D+","");
                    totalCpmList[i] = insightList5;
                    insightValue = insight.getValues().toString();
                }
            }               
        }  
    }
}
```

I'm also able to access other video insights through my application with the same format without any issues. So I'm wondering if I'm missing something when it comes to monetary values.

Comment: Can you please check what's your role on that page. Maybe it is "Analytics" only, so you can see insight but no monetization information.

Comment: @Norbert i have the solution, it’s because it was trying to get a video that wasn’t monetised.

Comment: @TomGood is there a way to check via api whether the video is monetized or not?

Comment: Getting same error when accessing in python or just a direct browser query on the API monetization metrics. How to solve it?